# Comments in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-jdbc, application.properties

I am very new in Spring world. I was using **application.properties** to set different port values. 
How can I comment some code in application.properties file?

Answer (score 6):

You start line comments with `#`

Answer (score 3):

Source : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

Starting a line with `#` or `!` will mark that line as comment.

```
# This is a comment 
! The exclamation mark can also mark text as comments.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `#` at start line, which ever property needs to be commentted.

Answer (score 1):

Any line that is pre-fixed with *#* before the data/code per line in your *APPLICATION.PROPERTIES* file shall be commented.

*For Example:*

> #datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:books_data
> #spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

The two lines in the *APPLICATION.PROPERTIES* are treated as comments.